# Column names from MySQL to CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, csv

i've a table in a database i would like to use as a contacts table to import into outlook.

what i would like the import to do is this:

name | email

andy | ds@ds.com <--name and email entered

at the moment i have this code:

```
(SELECT 'Name', 'Email') 
union all
(select E_Name, Email
INTO OUTFILE '/xampp/tmp/Sample.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM email WHERE 1)
```

this creates an excel file like this:

A   |   B   <-- excel column names

Name  |  Email

andy  |  ds@ds.com

i know if i pull the information using odbc connection it pulls the information the way i require, however i want it so the csv file is created with this information already in it, thus removing the need to do the odbc method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.  would slap myself.

```
SELECT  *
INTO OUTFILE '/xampp/tmp/Sample.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM
  (
SELECT 'Name' AS `E_Name`, 'Email' AS `Email`

UNION ALL

SELECT `E_Name`, `Email`
FROM `email`

) `sub_query`
```

before the new line i wasnt doing a return.  once i added this the csv can be imported into outlook no problem.  Thanks for the help though all.  ill leave this open incase anyone else has the same problem.

****face palm****

Comment: Note that this only works if all the columns in your table are a character type.  Otherwise you get the rather unhelpful error message "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns".

Answer (score 2):

I find this situation often. The easiest way I know is by using `sed`, that is a command-line utility for Unix.

Since you are working on Excel, I am assuming that you don't have a *nix system (Linux, BSD, etc). So I recommend you install Cygwin (you can get it [here](http://www.cygwin.com/)).

Then, open a Cygwin bash shell and write this in the command prompt:

```
mysql -h yourHost -u yourUser -pYourPassword yourDatabase -e"select e_name, email from email" | sed 's/\t/,/g' > yourOutput.csv
```

Let me explain each piece:

1. `mysql -h yourHost -u yourUser -pYourPassword yourDatabase -e"select..."` opens a session in MySQL, connects to `yourDatabase` and executes the query (the `-e` flag is used to execute a query). By default, the output is directed to the console as tab-separated values.
2. The pipe character `|` is used to redirect the output of the first command to the second command, instead to direct the output to the console.
3. `sed 's/\t/,/g''` substitutes every tab character (`\t`) with a comma
4. `> yourOutput.csv` redirects the result of the command to a file, called `yourOutput.csv`. You can specify a path of course.

More information about `sed` and redirecting: http://lowfatlinux.com

---

I know this can be cumbersome, but if you do this frequently, this will save you quite some time and headaches (the first time is the hardest, after a while it turns out to be very straightforward)

Hope this helps

---

About your comment:

> will this take the headers from mysql and make them headers in excel the way the odbc connection would?

In layman termns: an ODBC connection makes a table or view visible to the client program, so the client can use the data contained in the table or view. That means, of course, that the column names are visible to the client.

The solution I propose above is more like "exporting" the result of a `select` statement to a file.

If you don't want to install Cygwin, I have some news for you: The `>` redirection operator works on Windows' Command window... but I don't know of a Windows command line utility to replace characters. If you don't mind dealing with tabs instead of commas, this will work:

```
mysql -h yourHost, -u yourUser -pyourPassword yourDatabase -e"select..." > yourOutputFile.txt
```

This will export the result of the query to the `yourOutputFile.txt` file, as tab-separated values (which can be read by excel). As I mentioned in my comment, if you use aliases for your column names, these will be the column headers that will be exported.

Comment: will this take the headers from mysql and make them headers in excel the way the odbc connection would?

Comment: This will export the `select` query *with headers*. I use this frequently and it works. Of course, if your `select` query uses alias for the fields (e.g. `select e_name as name, email as mail from ...`), the headers will be the aliases.

Comment: If you are familiar with Linux command line, Cygwin will be quite easy to use for you. If you are not, it is a way to start learning.

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but I'm quite sure that there must be some php chunks of code that can make it easy to export .csv files. A quick Google-fu hit showed me this: http://www.sudobash.net/php-export-mysql-query-to-csv-file/

Answer (score 1):

Below query does union all on group concat(to dynamically fetch field names) and actual data.

```
-- group concat default is 1024, to avoid field names getting truncated we increase this value
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;

SELECT 
    CONCAT('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE \'/home/myuser/myfile.csv\' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ESCAPED BY \'\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' FROM (SELECT ',
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'', COLUMN_NAME, '\'')),
            ' UNION select * from YOUR_TABLE) as tmp')
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well from my understand of [INSERT INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) your query format is wrong as it is only writing the second insert into the output file.

Try this (tested)

```
SELECT  *
INTO OUTFILE '/xampp/tmp/Sample.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM
  (
    SELECT 'Name' AS `E_Name`, 'Email' AS `Email`

    UNION ALL

    SELECT `E_Name`, `Email`
    FROM `email`
    WHERE 1
  ) `sub_query`
```

**Note:** Not sure why you need the WHERE clause this can probably be taken out. The key point is to union the queries in a sub-query and then write that out to the file.

Comment: this would get the same result i would get, as in the headers are not excel headers, but just text in a cell.  this wont copy across to outlook as it requires header names and not just A, B. - thanks though, dont want to sound ungrateful